# Youtube .net api - search inside a playlist

Tags: .net, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm getting a 403 (forbidden) error when I try to search inside a google playlist. If I remove the .Query it works fine. I know the credentials work fine as I'm using them in other places in the application without a problem.

Am I going about this this wrong way, or is this not possible? I'm using version 1.8.0.0 of the api (new download).

```
void SearchPlaylistVideos(string playListId, string query)
{
    YouTubeQuery videoQuery = new YouTubeQuery(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/{0}", playListId));
    videoQuery.Query = query;

    Feed<Video> feed = CreateAuthenticatedRequest().Get<Video>(videoQuery);

    foreach (Video entry in feed.Entries) {
        //Response.Write("<br />" + entry.Title);
    }
}

YouTubeRequest CreateAuthenticatedRequest()
{
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings
                                        (
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.AppName"],
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.DeveloperKey"],
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.Email"],
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.Password"]
                                        );

    settings.Timeout = 1000000;
    return new YouTubeRequest(settings);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've worked on a *somewhat* similar problem:  Our client enters a YouTube query term into "The App", results for the *entire* query are returned, and then the client picks videos to persist to the App's db.  We can then have the app spit out a custom playlist to the client's site.  Visitors to this site can then search for videos with a search term.  We use [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) to run queries on these custom "App" lists.  With your situation, could you:

1. Query YouTube with a playlist ID.
2. Persist or cache the results (Url, title, length, etc.)
3. Perform queries on this set with Lucene.

It's definitely more resource (storage, cycles) intensive, and you may need to get up to speed with Lucene's API, but I concur with Данаил that the quick and easy way (YouTube allowing custom queries on playlists) won't work.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks. I awared the bounty to the other answer as it really answered my question first. Yours is a good way around the limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Just sniffed the HTTP request that the code is making - you got Error 403, because

> This service does not support the 'q' parameter.

This sounds like the YouTube API doesn't support full text search in specific playlist. Actually the `YouTubeQuery.Query` method just adds a string to your base URI, something like this (you can take a look at the FeedQuery and YouTubeQuery classes source):

```cs
url = baseUrl + string.Format("?q={0}", this.Query)
```

So, with `.Query`, your final url is this (if `query = "life"`):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/595A40209CB17411?q=life

Comment: Yes, I noticed this already with my playlist. I guess the real question is there another way to do this outside the .net API?